# react access dom elements by classname in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that places a bunch of records onto the page. The number of records can vary naturally, and as such I want to modify the width of the for those items which changes based on the number of items I have. This is what I have... (apparently it can't see the class elements, probably because the dom isn't rendered? but I thought the useEffect triggered after the dom was loaded...)

I get a document.getElementsByClassName() is undefined error...

```
....
function Thumbs(props)
{
    useEffect(()=>{
        // calculate how many records we have, and get the width
        // if i had 5, it would be 100%/5 records... this I can get... 
        const eachItemWidth = "20%";

        // loop/map over all the elements and set their NEW width
        document.getElementsByClassName("work").map(element=>{
            element.style.width = eachItemWidth;
        })
    },[]);

return (
        <div>
            <div className="works" id="worksStripe">
                {dataRecords.map(record =>
                    {

                    return(
                        <div className={`work`}>
                            <img src={`imgs/${record.coverImage}`} />
                        </div>
                    )
                    }
                )
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you have got htmlCollection when use `document.getElementsByClassName` which is not an array 
try to do

```
 const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("work"));
```

and then use

```
        elements.map(element=>{
            element.style.width = eachItemWidth;
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can replace `document.getElementsByClassName("work")` with:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".work").forEach(element => {
     element.style.width = eachItemWidth;
})
```